# snow leopard, mod_rewrite, codeigniter

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

hay guys, i'm having all sorts of mod_rewirte trouble in snow leopard. Anyone know any decent articles focused on snow leopard and mod_rewrite? Or perhaps a simple step by step guide. What i want to do is setup codeigniter so the urls looks 'pretty'.

so

```
localhost/~myusername/ci_app/index.php/mycontroller/myaction
```

would become

```
localhost/~myusername/ci_app/mycontroller/myaction
```

thanks

Comment: "all sorts of trouble"? Please say more. Are you using .htaccess files or the Apache config? (DON'T use .htaccess files if you can avoid them, they're more difficult and slightly buggy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [CodeIgniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), you should use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~myusername/ci_app/
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: where does this .htaccess file live? in my users Sites folder (localhost/~myuser)? or the actually serverDocument folder(localhost)?

Comment: @dotty: I thought that you want to put it in your `/Users/myusername/Sites/ci_app/` directory.

Comment: This works (after i added the line Options +FollowSymlinks)

However anything i cant load css/style.css any ideas?

Comment: @dotty: You’re probably just referencing your resources wrongly since relative URL paths like `css/style.css` are resolved from the URL path of your current document. So in the case you’re requesting `/~myusername/ci_app/index.php/mycontroller/myaction` the base URL path is exactly that URL path. And `css/style.css` would be resolved to `/~myusername/ci_app/index.php/mycontroller/css/style.css` and not `/~myusername/ci_app/css/style.css` as you may think. So use the absolute URL path `/~myusername/ci_app/css/style.css` to reference that resource or change the base URL (see BASE HTML element).